# Spark "Split" dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Java Spark.

I have `Dataset` that contains JSON strings that I'm reading as follow:

```
Dataset<Row> generalDS = spark.read().schema(jsonSchema).option("samplingRatio","0.1").json(jsonsDirPath);
```

Now, `generalDS` contains the following data:

```
code    data     load_date
--------------------------
 1      data...  20180823
 1      data...  20180823
 2      data...  20180823
 1      data..   20180823
 2      data...  20180823
 2      data...  20180823
```

Currently I'm split the `Dataset` as follow:

```
Dataset<Row> ds1 = generalDS.where("code = 1").select(columns1);
ds1.write().mode(mode1).format(format1).save(path1);
Dataset<Row> ds2 = generalDS.where("code = 2").select(columns2);
ds2.write().mode(mode2).format(format2).save(path2);
```

My question is if that is the best way to split the dataset or there is another **fast** way to do that?
Because I think that `where` take a long time.

I can't do `partitionBy` code and by load_date columns because I need to write different columns.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ` I need to write different columns`? Why `partitionBy` won't help to solve?

Comment: @MikhailDubkov because If i take the generalDS and make partitionBy("code").partitionBy("load_date") how can I select different columns? as you can see I make select to columns1 and to columns2

Comment: If you use different schemas and different formats, there is not much else that you can do.

Comment: No elegant way. What is slow? How many recs? This occurs sequentially.

Comment: @thebluephantom, The record amout is around 80B per day, for each batch is around 500M +-, Can you advise for me another elegant way? Thanks

Comment: I note no one else has commented, that may say something.

Comment: Are they evenly distributed? 250M+ each?

Comment: I see sampling ratio

Comment: @thebluephantom, No, Its 40% to code 1 / 60% to code 2, Its can change during the day, But all data its around 60/40

Comment: The sampling ration means you only want 10% of the data then? Or just for what you are doing now?

Comment: I just for what I'm doing now

Comment: @thebluephantom, btw, "samplingRatio" its only says that I want to take 10% data only to schema sampling, right?

Comment: Well that's why I ask, because from the documentation you can run into an issue, but apparently not here. Then why not 1% ratio?

Comment: Ok, I can change it

Comment: You state you think. You really need to try a sample of say 10M and try an .explain and see what Stages are genned. The reading will go in parallel, the actions sequentially - write that is. But if you play with number of partitions on your DS, then you can increase parallelism on write . There are may considerations here and I went thru them all myself. Also, cache  on the generalDS.